# Multiple Option Selector Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui

So i have been using Realm (a alternative to CoreData) in a Task Managing app, the user has predetermined tasks to choose from, these are in a Picker form so when the user selects the Task he needs via the Picker and clicks the "Add Task" a Task is added.

The problem is that the user can add one task at a time and i want the user to be able to add multiple tasks at once however Picker does not have the ability to select multiple options at once.

I have looked at a lot Multiple Selector Pickers on the internet but they do not return a String value that Realm needs to display the task.

Below is a sample piece of code:

```
struct AddTaskView: View {

var tasks = ["Study for the exam", "Clean your room"]
@State private var title: String = ""

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                  Section {
                      Picker("+", selection: $title) {
                          ForEach(tasks, id: \.self) {
                              Text($0)
                          }
                      }
                  } header: {
                    Text("Choose Your Task")
                }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Use a `Menu` or a `List`, list has a `selection` variable that works as a `Set`. `Picker` just isn't the right solution, you have to make your own.

Comment: i tried this but the problem is when the app is closed it reverts the changes